# How to return records which don't have a match in a tag relation table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join

Given the tag (ie: "animal"), how can I return the records from the objects table which **don't** have the tag "animal"?

Objects Table:

| object_id | object_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | dog |
| 3 | truck |
| 4 | car |

Tags Table:

| tag_id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | animal |
| 2 | vehicle |
| 3 | red |

Object Tags Table:

| tag_id | object_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

I'm doing something like this. However, 'dog' is still returning because it has a matching tag for 'red'.

```sql
SELECT o.* 
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN object_tags ot
   ON ot.object_id = o.object_id
LEFT JOIN tags t
   ON ot.tag_id = t.tag_id  
   AND LOWER(t.tag) = LOWER('animal') 
WHERE t.label IS NULL 
GROUP BY o.object_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm doing something like this. However, 'dog' is still returning
> because it has a matching tag for 'red'.

Based on the data example the only excluded record should be object_id=1

You could use `NOT EXISTS` which will exclude the records which have the `tag='animal'` :

```
select o.*
from objects o 
where not exists (select 1 from object_tags ot
                  inner join tags t on ot.tag_id=t.tag_id
                  where o.object_id=ot.object_id
                  and t.tag='animal'
                  );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b96e6ab628cb2347838c2e8f253d0475